# Vue HTML Template Optimization

Tags: vue.js

I have a question for you all. If I have a Vue component that contains a `<form>` with 9 fields and each of those fields is inputs. If in the Vue component the markup takes up a large number of lines would it make sense to break the `HTML` markup into separate child components? I couldn't find much on markup optimization in the Vue docs.

Comment: if the form contains multiple pages, breaking into multiple components makes sense else make it as single component itself

Comment: @Amaarrockz for example I have a component that is 120 lines of markup but all of the HTML markup is within the same form that contains 9 input fields in it. It is a lot of lines because the attributes of each field are on a new line for readability. Would I then take each input field and put it in its own component and then import it into the parent? Or what would be the best way to break that up? Or in this scenario is it best to just leave the form and its fields in just a single component?

Comment: the number of lines is becoz of indentation to give better readability so that shouldn't be a concern in terms of performance

Comment: You can keep it as a single component itself

Comment: @Amaarrockz so lets say on each of the 9 input fields in the form they all have the same classes... would it be wise to create a vue component that has a reusable input field that has attributes passed into it?

Comment: jus for the class name you need not create a reusable input field

Comment: if you gonna have a input field with unique actions that will be used in different parts of the app then go for a reusable component

Comment: @Amaarrockz but it wouldn't make sense to create a reusable input just to paste it 9 times in the same form then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports =
{
  ...
  chainWebpack: config =>
  {
    // condense whitespace in templates
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader').tap(options =>
    {
      options.compilerOptions = { whitespace: 'condense' };
      return options;
    });
    return config;
  }
};
```